# "No instance for .. ", Haskell'98 code on GHC7.8.3

Tags: haskell

I'm trying out the attached code for [linear regression with automatic differentiation](http://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/backpropogation-is-just-steepest-descent-with-automatic-differentiation-2/).
It specifies a datatype [Dual][2] made of two Floats, and declares it to be instance of Num, Fractional and Floating.
As in all fitting/regression tasks, there's a scalar cost function, parametrized by the fitting parameters c and m, and an optimizer which improves on estimates of these two parameters by gradient descent.

**Question**
I'm using GHC 7.8.3, and the authors explicitly mention that this is H98 code (I mentioned it in the title because it's the only substantial difference I can think of between my setup and the Author's, however plz correct if wrong).
Why does it choke within the definition of the cost function? 
My understanding is: the functions idD and constD map Floats to Duals, g is polymorphic (it can perform algebraic operations on Dual inputs because Dual inherits from Num, Fractional and Floating), and deriv maps Duals to Doubles.
The type signature for g (the eta-reduced cost function wrt the data) was inferred. I tried omitting it, and making it more general by substituting a Floating type constraint to the Fractional one.
Moreover, I tried converting the numeric types of c and m inline with (fromIntegral c :: Double), to no avail.

Specifically this code gives this error:

```
No instance for (Integral Dual) arising from a use of ‘g’
In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘g’
In the expression: flip g (constD c)
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘flip g (constD c) $ idD m’
```

Any hints, please? I'm sure it's a very noob question, but I just don't get it.

The complete code is the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module ADfw (Dual(..), f, idD, cost) where

data Dual = Dual Double Double deriving (Eq, Show)

constD :: Double -> Dual
constD x = Dual x 0

idD :: Double -> Dual
idD x = Dual x 1.0

instance Num Dual where
  fromInteger n             = constD $ fromInteger n
  (Dual x x') + (Dual y y') = Dual (x+y) (x' + y')
  (Dual x x') * (Dual y y') = Dual (x*y) (x*y' + y*x')
  negate (Dual x x')        = Dual (negate x) (negate x')
  signum _                  = undefined
  abs _                     = undefined

instance Fractional Dual where
  fromRational p = constD $ fromRational p
  recip (Dual x x') = Dual (1.0 / x) (- x' / (x*x))

instance Floating Dual where
   pi = constD pi
   exp   (Dual x x') = Dual (exp x)   (x' * exp x)
   log   (Dual x x') = Dual (log x)   (x' / x)
   sqrt  (Dual x x') = Dual (sqrt x)  (x' / (2 * sqrt x))
   sin   (Dual x x') = Dual (sin x)   (x' * cos x)
   cos   (Dual x x') = Dual (cos x)   (x' * (- sin x))
   sinh  (Dual x x') = Dual (sinh x)  (x' * cosh x)
   cosh  (Dual x x') = Dual (cosh x)  (x' * sinh x)
   asin  (Dual x x') = Dual (asin x)  (x' / sqrt (1 - x*x))
   acos  (Dual x x') = Dual (acos x)  (x' / (-sqrt (1 - x*x)))
   atan  (Dual x x') = Dual (atan x)  (x' / (1 + x*x))
   asinh (Dual x x') = Dual (asinh x) (x' / sqrt (1 + x*x))
   acosh (Dual x x') = Dual (acosh x) (x' / (sqrt (x*x - 1)))
   atanh (Dual x x') = Dual (atanh x) (x' / (1 - x*x))

-- example
-- f    = sqrt . (* 3) . sin
-- f' x = 3 * cos x / (2 * sqrt (3 * sin x)) 

-- linear fit sum-of-squares cost
-- cost :: Fractional s => s -> s -> [s] -> [s] -> s
cost m c x y = (/ (2 * (fromIntegral $ length x))) $
               sum $ zipWith errSq x y
  where
    errSq xi yi = zi * zi
      where
        zi = yi - (m * xi + c)

-- test data
x_ = [1..10]
y_ = [a | a <- [1..20], a `mod` 2 /= 0]

-- learning rate
gamma = 0.04

g :: (Integral s, Fractional s) => s -> s -> s
g m c = cost m c x_ y_

deriv (Dual _ x') = x'

 z_ = (0.1, 0.1) : map h z_

 h (c, m) = (c - gamma * cd, m - gamma * md) where
   cd = deriv $ g (constD m) $ idD c
   md = deriv $ flip g (constD c) $ idD m

 -- check for convergence
 main = do
   take 2 $ drop 1000 $ map (\(c, m) -> cost m c x_ y_) z_
   take 2 $ drop 1000 $ z_
```

where the test data x_ and y_ are arrays and the learning rate gamma a scalar.

[2]: The two fields of a Dual object are in fact adjoint one with the other, if we see the derivative as an operator

Comment: If anybody stumbles upon this example, the bug is in using a list comprehension to generate the data x_ and y_. If you declare instead their entries explicitly e.g. x_=[1,2,4,10,2] etc., It Just Works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `(Integral s, Fractional s)` makes no sense; `Integral` is for Euclidean domains (ones with `div` and `mod`), while `Fractional` is for fields (ones with `/`).  If you have true division all your remainders are going to be zero... .

I think the problem is `y_`'s attempt to filter to odd numbers.  Haskell 98 defines a 'stepped' range form for numbers, so you could write `y_` as `[1,3..19]`.  That should allow `y_` to be used at the type `[Dual]`, which should allow `g` to use it without needing the `Integral` constraint.

Edit: Ørjan Johansen points out that you need an `Enum` instance for `Dual` as well, which is actually fairly easy to implement (this is pretty standard for numeric types; I basically copied GHC's instance for `Double` (which is identical to its instance for `Float`, for example)):

```
instance Enum Dual where
    succ x              = x + 1
    pred x              = x - 1
    toEnum              = fromIntegral
    fromEnum (Dual x _) = fromEnum x
    enumFrom            = numericEnumFrom
    enumFromTo          = numericEnumFromTo
    enumFromThen        = numericEnumFromThen
    enumFromThenTo      = numericEnumFromThenTo
```

Comment: The type constraint was inferred, don't look at me.. I tried omitting it but same error.
In the meanwhile I figured it out! the current definition of g makes it dependent on the type of the input data x_, y_ . 
In particular, 
`[1..4] :: (Num t, Enum t) => [t]` , whereas
`[1,2,3,4] :: Num t => [t]`

I took the shortcut of declaring the data as list comprehensions but it unnecessarily overconstrains the code. Go figure. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @ocramz, no, it's `mod` that constrains the code, as jcast said. That's where your `Integral` constraint came from.

Comment: `[1,3..19]` won't work, as `Dual` has no `Enum` instance either.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I've never liked the way Haskell does numeric ranges, but lack of an `Enum` instance on a numeric type is a lot easier to fix than a `(Integral s, Fractional s)` constraint is.

Answer (score 2):

In the original code, I don't see a type signature for `g`. In your code, you have specifically written

```
g :: (Integral s, Fractional s) => s -> s -> s
```

The error message says there's no `Integral` instance for `Dual`. The code manually defines instances for `Num` and `Fractional`, but not `Integral`.

I'm not actually sure why `g` needs to be `Integral`. If you remove that constraint, the code may even work...

**EDIT:** It seems the `Integral` instance is necessary because of your use of `mod` to generate test data. I'm not really sure what this huge block of code does, but I suspect if you apply `fromIntegral` to convert everything to (say) `Double`, then it may work.

(I suspect making `Dual` an instance of `Integral` is probably not what the original authors intended. Then again, I don't really understand the code, so...)

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the constraint does not change matters. I'll try by making `Dual` an instance of `Integral`. Could it also be that the pragma {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-} interferes somehow? I just copied from the original but didn't look its definition up..

Comment: You cannot convert just to `Double`, it needs to be `Dual`. But `fromIntegral` should still work, since `Dual` does have a `Num` instance.